# How to manipulate window prototype in a <browser> element?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

What I'm doing right now is:

When `<browser src="..." />` loads, I attach data into its `.contentWindow`:

```js
frame.addEventListener("load",function(){
    this.contentWindow.someMethod = function(){};
},true);
```

Now I want to know if there is a way to do this earlier, into the `<browser>`'s window prototype, or any Window prototype, as for example I can do in the "current" window:

```js
// [W]indow is the constructor
Window.prototype.test = function(){ alert("hello"); };
// [w]indow is the instance
window.test();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently two ways to inject properties into a window before any JavaScript code runs. Usually, [`content-document-global-created` notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents) is simpler. The other is [implementing `nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMGlobalPropertyInitializer). Both allow you to get notified when a new window loads and before that window runs JavaScript code.

Here is the approximate code for doing it with the observer notification:

```js
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
const Cu = Components.utils;
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

var myObserver =
{
  QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIObserver, Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference]),

  observe: function(subject, topic, data)
  {
    if (topic == "content-document-global-created" &&
        subject instanceof Ci.nsIDOMWindow &&
        subject.location.hostname == "example.com")
    {
      XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(subject).someMethod = function() {};
    }
  }
};

var observerService = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                        .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(myObserver, "content-document-global-created", true);
```

Comment: @Wladimir - can you please specify where exactly to put this code? I tried to put it into a script referenced in <overlay> element in my .xul file, but it does not seem to have any effect.